# How to access the component of a child object inside another child object using a tag?

Tags: unity, c#

As the question above, I need to access the collider component of a child object that is inside its parent object which is also a child to its parent object. I tried this line of code below but it only detects the first child object in a hierarchy. Since I have the same name for each child, I need to access all of them using a tag instead. Any help would be appreciated

```
GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Level").transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.transform.Find("Platform").gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
```

Comment: Have you tried GameObject.GetComponentInChildren ?

Comment: It seems like this is a simple case of poor research effort.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I just have to use this code at Start() instead since I'm searching the child objects with tag. Problem solved.

```
foreach (GameObject gameObject in GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Platform"))
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
    }
```